# How to extract JSON data from a URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I am trying to extract data from the following URL:
http://content.warframe.com/dynamic/worldState.php

... however I can't quite figure out exactly how.

The link contains JSON data which the developers of the online game **Warframe** make available. Basically it just shows server information, among other game-related info.

Here's a snippet of the first part of it:

```
{
  "Version": 9,
  "BuildLabel": "2014.08.06.16.27/7muOn6ZYQ4Brw+vtYhsKYQ",
  "Time": 1407561753,
  "Events": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$id": "5398e94d075fcb5d2afc5737"
      },
      "Msg": "Loki Prime Access! ",
      "Prop": "https://warframe.com/prime-access",
      "Date": {
        "sec": 1402529771,
        "usec": 0
      }
    },
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can extract the data into a spreadsheet. From what I *(think)* I understand, I need to use JavaScript from within HTML to convert / extract the JSON code and parse it into a more easily-read format? I'm just not sure how quite to go about doing this, and I would love if someone could share a working example - perhaps a bit of code which would extract the "9" out of the "Version"?

I am clearly a beginner when it comes to programming. I know HTML / CSS fairly well, however I have basically **no** JavaScript experience. I'd like to learn more about JavaScript and JSON, and I always feel the best way to learn is to combine it with something you enjoy - in this case, the game I play.

If more information would be helpful, please let me know and I will try my best.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: copy and paste your output json data here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and it will give you array structure of your json data, you can try json_decode() of php. which will give you same array structure.

Comment: Oh, wow, thank you god, lol. That website makes it MUCH, MUCH easier to read. I'm not sure how I would go about doing the json_decode() in php? (I'm not familiar with PHP at all either) but I did get the online tool to work. Thank you! I'm still not sure how I would extract, for example, the Version label from the JSON code though. I mean.. I can see it, but I'm trying to extract the value only. Perhaps I should reorganize my question, now that you've given me a much better way to explain to people what I'm trying to achieve =D

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to decode JSON data to an array.

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://content.warframe.com/dynamic/worldState.php"); // Requires allow_url_fopen to be enabled in php.ini
$array = json_decode($contents, true); // Remove true if you want to work with an object instead of an array

echo $array['Version']; // Outputs 9
echo $array['Events'][0]['Msg']; // Outputs 'Loki Prime Access!'

var_dump($array); // Dumps the array, read through it and you'll get a good overview of how it works.
```

Comment: Thank you for your code example... Sadly I am not able to get it to work... perhaps the question I asked is out of my league; I didn't realize the answer required knowledge of JavaScript, JSON, HTML, and PHP, lol... I was kind of hoping there was a way to simply use a bit of JavaScript within HTML to extract the data. I have a feeling I need to go learn PHP, lol... at least I'm on the right track now! Thank you.

Comment: You tagged the question with PHP though. You could easily use the jQuery [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) function with the [parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) function, without any need of PHP. I'll edit my answer with a JS snippet of it aswell.

Comment: Oh, sorry; I tagged it with PHP because stackoverflow recommended I do so (this is my first ever post here). Thank you for your help. I may not understand much here, but I at least know what I need to learn so I can understand it, hehe. I will be sure to check your answer again once I've learned more! Thanks again.